# How to add a new entity in CiviCRM extension

Tags: drupal, extension, developer, civix

As I am new to CiviCRM. I am trying to create a new entity for my extension to add some new data in `database schema`. The documentation I am following to create a new entity is: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/#generate-entity

**What I have done using the documentation till Now:**

- I have created successfully new extension under the folder `<drupalroot>/sites/.../civicrm/ext/`
- The extension is `enabled` from the **CiviCRM » Administer » System Settings » Extensions**
- I have used `civix generate:entity MyEntity` to generate a new entity.
- The entity is generated under the `ext/myextension/`.
- This command has created seketal files successfully.
- I have edited the `xml` file to add fields for entity *(table)*.
- Now, **1 - 3** points are done.

I have got stucked when following the point **4 - end**. The overflow and files and folder structure is defined in these point and how to generate or run the `DAO file` to run `sql` to create new table in `database schema` looks weird to me.  **I am using** `Drupal v7`, `Civicrm v4.7.2 for drupal 7.x` and `XAMPP` on `Windows OS` envirnoment. I don't now what I have to do after it to successfully create and use entity in my `CiviCRM` extension.

Please help me to solve this problem. I am very thankful to you in advance.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install civicrm using buildkit to ensure you have all the dependencies / tools / files.
Then have a look here: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/

Examples of extensions that have done it (see ./bin/setup.sh for a scripted method of DAO creation): https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer
And https://github.com/3sd/civicrm-sms-conversations/

Comment: Thank you. I have to try buildkit and then response you back.