# Generate new entity in CiviCRM extension

Tags: extension, developer

I have same problem mentioned here: [How to add a new entity in CiviCRM extension](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/19155/5312)

I followed the documentation to generate skeletal files and completed steps 1 - 3. However I get stucked when following the point 4.
In point 4 I've been able to complete sub steps a,b,c but I'm getting the following error when trying to run the command from sub step d:

```
$ ./setup.sh -g

+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -n 1 -a -d /var/www/html/civi-demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/./../xml ']'
+ pushd /var/www/html/civi-demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/./../xml
/var/www/html/civi-demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/xml /var/www/html/civi-demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin
+ '[' -z 3306 ']'
+ PHP_MYSQL_HOSTPORT=localhost:3306
+ php -d mysql.default_host=localhost:3306 -d mysql.default_user=user -d mysql.default_password=pass GenCode.php schema/Schema.xml '' drupal

civicrm_domain.version := 4.7.29

Parsing schema description schema/Schema.xml
Extracting database information
Extracting table information
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Civi\Core\Container' not found in /var/www/html/civi-demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php on line 113
```

The line throwing the error is the following:

\Civi\Core\Container::boot($loadFromDB);

Seems it tries to access the class Container in the global namespace but cannot find it.
I searched for the class and it exists in the following path:

/var/www/html/civi-demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php

What can be the problem?
Should I modify class CRM/Core/Config.php and add aditional code to try to access the Container class in a different way?

Thanks in advance!